# SDL 2.0 build error using VS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

I was following [Lazy Foo's tutorial for getting started with SDL](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php).
So I followed all the instructions on the page and got some compilation error.

Here's the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
      std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   SDL_Quit();

   return 0;
}
```

> ```
> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetError referenced in function _SDL_main
> Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main
> Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function _SDL_main
> Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in __tmainCRTStartup
> ```

I've double checked to make sure my settings are correct.

Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories

> ```
> C:\Users\Minkai\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SDL2-2.0.3\include;$(IncludePath)
> ```

Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories

> ```
> C:\Users\Minkai\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x64;$(LibraryPath)
> ```

Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies

> ```
> SDL2.lib;SDL2main.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
> ```

Configuration Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem
I tried switching between Window and Console, doesn't work.

I put my SDL2.dll everywhere in the project just to make sure.

Some information:

1. Using the latest SDL SDL2-devel-2.0.3-VC.zip
2. IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
   Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
3. OS is 64-bit Windows 8.1

Comment: I know you double checked it, but are you sure you didn't forget to link SDL2.lib (don't forget the "2" in SDL2.lib)

Comment: Yeap, checked that. Updated my post to show all the settings.

Comment: do you tried to use the x86 folder for libraries? even your computer using a 64-bit os, your project is by default a x86 project.

Comment: Try changing the order in additional dependecies and place `SDL2main.lib` before `SDL2.lib`. I have a vague memory that the order might matter (at least it used to iirc). But I think the most likely cause of the problem is that you include 64-bit libs and link with a dll built for x86.

Comment: Yes! It worked. I just needed to use x86 folder for libraries and change SDL2.dll to the x86 version.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it has been resolved and don't need answering any longer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to build an x64 SDL 2.0 application with VS2013, you need to create the platform and setup the following from your project properties:

1. "Project Properties" -> "Configuration Manager" -> "Active solution platform" drop-down menu and select "< New... >"
2. In the "New Solution Platform" dialog, choose "x64" in the "Type or select the new platform" drop-down menu
3. In the same dialog, leave "Copy settings from" on Win32, check "create new project platform" check-box

   Note : Yet after these 3 steps, your VC++ Directories for this project will all be correctly set for the x64 flavor (check VC++ Directories in the project settings).
4. Make sure (or setup) your "C/C++" -> "General" -> "Additional Include Directories" contains a path to your "SDL/include" folder
5. Make sure (or setup) your "Linker" -> "General" -> "Additional Library Directories" contains a path to your "SDL/lib/x64" folder
6. Make sure (or setup) your "Linker" -> "Input" -> "Additional Dependencies" contains "SDL2.lib;" and "SDL2main.lib;"
7. Your sample should compile and link now. Make sure your executable can access "SDL/lib/x64/SDL2.dll" (eg. paste it next your exe) in order to run it